# Jquery Autocomplete: the value passed to the ajax call is wrong

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, jquery-ui, autocomplete

I have a reusable function of jquery Autocomplete in a file function.js. The function has as parameters the url for the ajax call and some additional values ​​taken from the fields of a form 
In another file, anag.js, I have several calls to this function.

The problem is that when it is executed, the value of the form fields remain the old one.

For example:

```
field prov = LI   
field city = Livorno
```

When I change the value of the `prov` in `MO`, the function call autocomplete continues to have the value if field `prov = LI`.

I think it's a problem of binding function but can not figure out where is the error.

**Autocomplete function (function.js)**

```
function ajaxAutocomplete(elemId, dMinlength, dUrl, extraData){
    $("#" + elemId).autocomplete({
        source: function( request, response ) {
            $.ajax({
                url: dUrl,
                dataType: "json",
                data: 'term=' + request.term + '&' + extraData,
                success: function(data) {
                    response($.map(data, function(item) {
                        return { label: item.res };
                    }));
                }
            });
        },
        minLength: dMinlength
    });
};
```

**Call to autocomplete function (anag.js)**

```
$(function() {
    ajaxAutocomplete('luogo_nascita', 2, getBaseURL() + "/default/city_selector", 'prov=' + $("#prov").val() );
});
```

Thanks